# Can a function pointer be passed as an argument without its parameters?

Tags: c, function-pointers

So, there is function qsort in stdlib.h and its prototype is as follows;

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

As you can see, it needs a function function pointer as its last argument.

compare function is defined as follows:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b){

     return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);

}
```

now when I call qsort, I only to declare function pointer like

```
int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*) = &compare;
```

and pass `cmp` as the last argument to the function, along with the other parameters. No need to specify the parameters of the function `compare`.

Here's is my main function

```
main(){
        int (*cmp) (const void* , const void*);
        cmp = &compare;
    
        int iarray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        qsort(iarray, sizeof(iarray)/sizeof(*iarray), sizeof(*iarray), cmp);
    
        int c = 0;
        while (c < sizeof(iarray)/sizeof(*iarray)){
            printf("%d \t", iarray[c]);
            c++;
        }
}
```

I got this code online and just cant figure why I don't need to pass any parameters to the function pointer `cmp`.

Comment: You don't need to pass any parameters to `cmp()` because you're not calling it. It is called from within the `qsort()` function. Incidentally, you could just put `compare` as the last parameter of your call to `qsort()`. There's no need to declare another variable for this purpose.

Comment: @Aman Jain Parameters are not passed. Parameters are declarations. It is arguments that are passed. And the function qsort internally passes to your function two pointers of the type const void *.

Comment: @AmanJain It does this according its algorithm implementation.

Comment: Okay, so if I change the type of arguments for the function compare to integer, will it still work?

Comment: The 4th argument to qsort is the function that qsort will call to compare two values.  It might be educational to add a `printf` in compare that describes the arguments it is being called with so you can trace the action.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow what kind of algorithm implementation?

Comment: No, changing the parameter types will not work, since they must be void pointers.  `qsort` is going to call compare and pass it pointers to int.

Comment: @WilliamPursell so, actually what pointers does qsort pass to it? does it takes the values from the first argument which is array and then pass that pointer to cmp?

Comment: @AmanJain I think the quick sort algorithm.

Comment: @AmanJain The function qsort passes to the comparison function pointers to two elements of the array. What is unclear?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yeah. Actually that cleared up. So, would you happen to know if I wanted to implement something like that how would I pass those pointers to the function?

Comment: @AmanJain You can pass them silently.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the parameters are passed within `qsort` function, the function that you passed the function pointer to. Like:

```c
/*                                                                       
 * qsort.c                                                               
 *                                                                       
 * This is actually combsort.  It's an O(n log n) algorithm with         
 * simplicity/small code size being its main virtue.                     
 */ 

...

void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,                        
       int (*compar) (const void *, const void *))                       
{                                                                        
    size_t gap = nmemb;                                                  
    size_t i, j;                                                         
    char *p1, *p2;                                                       
    int swapped;                                                         
                                                                         
    if (!nmemb)                                                          
        return;                                                          
                                                                         
    do {                                                                 
        gap = newgap(gap);                                               
        swapped = 0;                                                     
                                                                         
        for (i = 0, p1 = base; i < nmemb - gap; i++, p1 += size) {       
            j = i + gap;                                                 
            if (compar(p1, p2 = (char *)base + j * size) > 0) {
            //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            //  here calls the compare function
            //
                memswap(p1, p2, size);                                   
                swapped = 1;                                             
            }                                                            
        }                                                                
    } while (gap > 1 || swapped);                                        
}
```

Function pointers are usually passed without parameters, since most of time  function pointers are used to accomplish *callback* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)). If the parameters are passed together, it should be intended to implement *lazy evaluation*.